# Not able to execute Jbehave with Gradle using Serenity Framewrok

Tags: gradle, junit4, jbehave

I am using Serenity - JBehave framework. After creation of sample script, I am able to execute Junit runner class from eClipse however when I am trying to execute any of the below command from command prompt it is giving me error.

```
$gradle clean test aggregate
$gradle clean test
$gradle clean build
```

The error message is same in all cases, as below:

```
org.gradle.TestRunnerClass > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.RuntimeException
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

1 test completed, 1 failed
:test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///C:/$ /build/reports/tests/index.html
```

Below are the details:
Test Runner class:

```
package org.gradle;

import net.serenitybdd.jbehave.SerenityStories;

public class TestRunnerClass extends SerenityStories{}
```

Sample Step Definition class:

```
package org.gradle.stepDef;

import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Step;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Steps;

import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Given;
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Then;
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.When;

public class StepDefSticky {
    @Given("User is on Sticky note home page")
    public void givenUserIsOnStickyNoteHomePage() {
      System.out.println("I am in Given");
    }

    @When("User clicks on Add Note button")
    public void whenUserClicksOnAddNoteButton() {
        System.out.println("I am in When");
    }

    @Then("Sticky note pop up should get open")
    public void thenStickyNotePopUpShouldGetOpen() {
        System.out.println("I am in Then");
    }
}
```

Please see the package structure carefully.

Below is the build.gradle I am using

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'net.serenity-bdd.aggregator'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'
def poiVersion = "3.10.1"

repositories {
    maven { url "repoUrl" }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "repoURL" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("net.serenity-bdd:serenity-gradle-plugin:1.0.47")
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:0.6'
        classpath 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:0.12.0'
    }
}

ext {
    bintrayBaseUrl = 'https://api.bintray.com/maven'
    bintrayRepository = 'maven'
    bintrayPackage = 'serenity-cucumber'
    projectDescription = 'Serenity Cucumber integration'
    if (!project.hasProperty("bintrayUsername")) {
        bintrayUsername = 'wakaleo'
    }
    if (!project.hasProperty("bintrayApiKey")) {
        bintrayApiKey = ''
    }
    serenityCoreVersion = '1.0.47'
    cucumberJVMVersion = '1.2.2'
}

dependencies {

    testCompile('junit:junit:4.11')
    testCompile('org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.0')
    testCompile('org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.7')


    //JBehave jar files
    testCompile 'net.serenity-bdd:core:1.0.47'
    testCompile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-jbehave:1.0.21'
    testCompile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit:1.0.47'

    // Apache POI plugin for excel read
    compile "org.apache.poi:poi:${poiVersion}"
    compile "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:${poiVersion}"
    compile "org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:1.1"
}


   gradle.startParameter.continueOnFailure = true

uploadArchives {
    repositories { flatDir { dirs 'repos' } }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { gradleVersion = '2.3' }
```

I have stored the .story file under the src/test/resources package.

Please help me to understand where I am making mistake. Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Which class can't be found? And please attach the build.gradle file.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the build.gradle. Now I have updated it. When I am executing any of the mentioned commands from the question from command prompt, it gives the class not found exception. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Enable standard out and standard error in your build.gradle file:

```
test {
    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams = true
    }
}
```

And to make sure all your stories run, add a TestSuite class:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ Story1.class, Story2.class})
public class TestSuite { }
```

Note:  Story1 & Story2 are the names of the test runners to match a JBehave Gherkin files  named Story1.story & Story2.story & step files names Story1Steps.java & Story2Steps.java according to Serenity naming conventions.